# Using return vs no return in recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, return

Here is code to reverse an array using recursion

Using **return rev(arr,++start,--end);**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void rev(int arr[],int start,int end)
{
    if(start >= end)
    {
        return;
    }
    int temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    return rev(arr,++start,--end);
}

void reverse(int arr[],int size)
{
    rev(arr,0,size-1);
}
```

Using **rev(arr,++start,--end);**

```
void rev(int arr[],int start,int end)
{
    if(start >= end)
    {
        return;
    }
    int temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    rev(arr,++start,--end);
}

void reverse(int arr[],int size)
{
    rev(arr,0,size-1);
}
```

They both give **same output** 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

What is the difference between **using return and not using return** with rev here?

Comment: In this specific example there is no difference because the `return` is the last statement of the function, and the thing being "returned" is `void`. You can confirm this by comparing the compiler output. They are identical.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am new to recursion will you please explain it through some other example.

Comment: In many cases you want to return a value from recursion but in this case the function is a void function

Comment: Since `rev()` returns `void`,   `return rev(arr,++start,--end);` is equivalent in net effect to `rev(arr,++start,--end); return;`   or (since it is the last statement in the function before the closing `}`) to `rev(arr,++start,--end);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.

From `9.6.3 [stmt.return]`:

> A return statement with no operand shall be used only in a function
> whose return type is *cv* void, a constructor (15.1), or a destructor
> (15.4). A return statement with an operand of type void shall be used
> only in a function  whose return type is *cv* void.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Flowing off
> the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with a *cv* void
> return type is equivalent to a return with no operand.

Because the type of the function call expression is the *cv*-qualified return type of the function as defined in its signature, and because your function is defined to return `void`, then the three that follow are equivalent:

```cpp
void f() {
    //stuff
    f();
    return;
}

void g() {
    //same stuff
    return g();
}

void h() {
    //same stuff
    h();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

void rev();

void rev(){
    return 1;
}
int main(){
    int val=rev();
    cout<<rev<<endl;
    return 0;
}

g++ test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘void rev()’:
test.cpp:7:9: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning ‘void’ [-fpermissive]
    7 |  return 1;
      |         ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10:13: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   10 |  int val=rev();
```

Compiler is generating error that if return type is void we cannot return any value and there is no need to return any value because the array which is passed as an argument is being modified.

Why your compiler is not generating error because both of your methods are returning noting.

```
void foo(){
    return;//returns nothing
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void rev(int arr[],int start,int end)
{
    if(start >= end)
    {
        return;
    }
    int temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    return rev(arr,++start,--end);//doesn't returns any value
}

void reverse(int arr[],int size)
{
    rev(arr,0,size-1);
}

Using rev(arr,++start,--end);

void rev(int arr[],int start,int end)
{
    if(start >= end)
    {
        return;
    }
    int temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    rev(arr,++start,--end);
}

void reverse(int arr[],int size)
{
    rev(arr,0,size-1);
}
```

Comment: This answer, while factually correct, does not answer the question as asked. Consider rewriting to address the original question.